# Steam showing weird pop up after buying some DLCs for CK2

Tags: steam, crusader-kings-2

I bought some DLCs for CK2 at Steam. Since then, Steam is showing the following pop up before launching the game.

[image]

After that, it doesn't ask me to enter the keys at all. The DLCs are showing as activated and owned both on Steam and PDX Forums. Do I need to keep these keys somewhere just in case? Found a discussion on the issue on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/203770/discussions/0/828923952097196674/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CrusaderKings/comments/3n6akr/everytime_i_launch_the_game_steam_talks_to_me/) where people seem to suggest it is a relic of the olden days and I should ignore it. Since those threads are a bit old, I am wondering if something has changed?

Comment: I can't say for this specific game, but you can always see the CD key when it's needed from the main Steam interface (the mini-menu on the right of the page), so I think you can ignore it for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need these keys. You can safely click "Don't show me this again."

In any case, if you ever want to see this dialog again, you can go to the library page for CK2 and click the CD Key link on the right hand side:

[image: Position of CD Key in the Links section]

This link also shows up in the Steam overlay.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said: You can just click "Don't show me again". It informs you about these keys because you can use them in the paradox forum to update your settings related to which games and dlcs you own. This gives you some nice little icons for your user and allows you access to the support forums. On the other hand: the forum now has the functionality to link your steam account and just fetch your owned games from there.